# Match and Find all values in an array from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array with values like

```
$slugs= array('abraham_lincoln','alan_watts','albert_camus','anne_frank','a_p_j_abdul_kalam','aristotle','arnold_schwarzenegger','audrey_hepburn','ayn_rand','barack_obama','benjamin_franklin','bill_gates','bob_dylan','bob_ross','brene_brown','bruce_lee','bryson_tiller','carl_sagan','chanakya','charles_bukowski','charlie_chaplin');
```

I want to check if the same slug exist in the database or not.

```
$selectslug="SELECT `slug` FROM `authors_list`";
$done=mysqli_query($con, $selectslug )or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

single slug comes from

```
foreach($slugs as  $slug)
{ echo $slug; }
```

and single slug from DB comes as

```
foreach($done as  $data)
{ echo $data;}
```

So How can I use the code below

```
if (in_array($slug, $data))
{
      echo $slug." Found<br />";
      }
    else
      {
      echo $slug." Match not found<br />";
}
```

without repeating it number of times of $slug or $data?

Comment: Why do you use `in_array` ? You have a string `$slug` and another string `$data`, you can compare them with just `==` !

Comment: Both data $slug and $data are in different foreach and so I have to use foreach in second foreach which makes the checking process of same variable to the number of values I have in array. Like if my $slugs array has 20 values it checks $data for 20 times before going to the next one. How can I solve it? Even if I use `==` ??

Comment: Can't you just use a query to return the existing slugs? `"SELECT slug FROM authors_list where slug in (".implode(",", $slugs).")"`?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to retrieve slugs which are in database and then echo in a foreach.

```
$existanceSlugs = array_intersect($slugs, $done);

foreach($existanceSlugs as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

if you wanna get slugs which are not in database, you can simply use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) php function.

Comment: Thanks, That works for Found item, what about not found Variables?